# What could cause that opener doens't work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, window

I'm opening a popup window from a website and would like to send a message from that popup to the main window: `<a href="javascript:opener.closeInfo()">CLOSE</a>`

The message doesn't get to the main window - it seems that the `opener` window is not recognized. What could be the reason that it's not working?

Main window link:

```
<a href="javascript:authorize('https://www.example.com/oauth/test-service.php
    ')">AUTHORIZE</a>
```

JS:

```
var oauthWindow;

function authorize(service){
oauthWindow = window.open(service, "oauthWindow", "toolbar=no, titlebar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width=600, height=400, top="+((screen.height/2)-(400/2))+", left="+((screen.width/2)-(600/2)));
}

function closeInfo(){
alert("OK");
}
```

Both site are on the same domain.